# Conflict in .htaccess when add redirect 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have trouble with adding some commands in my old .htaccess at root folder:
Before:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex category.php index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^search/$ category.php?category=search&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^module_([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?([^/\.]*)/?([^/\.]*)/?([^/\.]*)/?$ module.php?class=$1&pv1=$2&pv2=$3&pv3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^((print)_)?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]*)/?([^/\.]*)/?([^/\.]*)/?$ category.php?category=$3&id_module=$4&pv1=$5&pv2=$6&showtype=$2

php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_value upload_max_filesize 52428800
php_value error_reporting 6135
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400
```

After adding this strings:

```
Redirect 301 /sect_25/ /stati/126/12/#read
Redirect 301 /sect_24/ /stati/126/9/#read
Redirect 301 /sect_23/ /stati/126/10/#read
Redirect 301 /articles/sect_19/ /stati/126/13/#read
```

Page is not available anymore:
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Help somebody, please!

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) ([`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)); use only one of them to avoid conflicts. You could, for example, turn your `Redirect` directives into `RewriteRule` directives:

```
RewriteRule ^sect_25/ /stati/126/12/#read [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^sect_24/ /stati/126/9/#read [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^sect_23/ /stati/126/10/#read [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^articles/sect_19/ /stati/126/13/#read [L,R=301]
```

Now just make sure to put these externally redirecting rules in front of you other internally rewriting rules.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the second URL should be a full URL:

```
Redirect 301 /sect_25/ http://your.domain.tld/stati/126/12/#read
```